# Cloudflare API returns error 400 Bad Request

Tags: cloudflare

I don't know what I  am doing wrong, but when I try to post  to cloudflare's API I keep on getting an error message that reads:

```
Request failed with status code 400
```

I am using axios to make the request, e.g.:

```
 const headers = {
    'X-Auth-Email': MY_EMAIL,
    'X-Auth-Key': MY_KEY,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  const account = MY_ACCOUNT_ID

  await axios
    .post(
      'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones',
      { name: 'domainexample12345.com' , account: { id: account }, jump_start: true },
      { headers: headers }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      return res.result
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('did not create DNS entries: ', JSON.stringify(err))
      return 1
    })
```

When I use cURL, it works fine. I have also tried using the cloudflare npm module and it just returns the same error.

I have also even tried using a token with full access and still get the same error.

I just whish cloudflare could give more insight on the error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue with Cloudflare using PHP/cURL to perform a PUT request.

I was using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
```

It was working well when Cloudflare was disabled and producing a 400 error when Cloudflare was enabled:

```
<html><head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head><body><center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center><hr><center>cloudflare</center></body></html>
```

**I replaced it with:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
```

and it fixed the issue. Many Cloudflare customers have been reporting this since 2018 but it seems this still hasn't been fixed nor documented officially.